# SymmetricDS - Only "copy" transformation_type seems to work

Tags: symmetricds

I have several transformations to test sync to multiple tables to one table, or one table with several fields to one table with less fields. All that works correctly, however, when I try to change "copy" type to "const" or "bsh" in transform_column table, source value is still copied into target field without doing what I write in "transform_expression" field.
Any idea why is this happening?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What version of SymmetricDS were you using?  Early on, the staging area was not being cleared so while developing transforms you could end up with already transformed data being delivered.  There are lots of improvements for transformations in the later 3.6 versions of SymmetricDS.

Comment: THanks for your answer. I was using 3.6.9 version.